# How To Automate ETL Testing without using any Automation Tool?

Tags: testing, scripting, automation, build-automation, etl

How to I automate the ETL Testing without using any Automation Tool with the help of some Scripting Language

Comment: Have you tried http://benilovj.github.io/dbfit/

Answer (score 0):

Python is one of the best scripting language which can be used for ETL Testing, We can pull the data from source and target and then compare both the data sets using python script.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Try to add a minimal example.